# Editing author of a node Drupal 6

Tags: workflows

After some painful searching, I think I've deduced a solution (to try) to fix my real problem. That solution involves changing the Author of a node.

The real problem is the Workflow tab showing on a few products for Anonymous users. I've been all through all the permissions, rules and workflows. What I found was that if an Authenticated user who created some content is deleted, that content is assigned to an Anonymous author.

So, I was trying to find the data in phpmyAdmin to edit one there as a test but I haven't found the information.

As the super user, I cannot edit the authorship of a node as I haven't found a tab/setting etc to do so.

Can anybody steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node author is usually editable in the 'Authoring Information' tab/section of the node-edit page. If that data isn't available for you (may have been removed by another module or other customization).

If you're comfortable editing the data in the database (via phpMyAdmin or another tool), have a look at the `node` table. You will see that each row contains a value in the `uid` column - this refers to the user id (uid) of the authoring user. User ids can be matched up to the corresponding users in the `users` table. Simply update the `uid` value in the `node` table for the appropriate nodes (likely ones with `uid = 0`) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working (the phpmyadmin method)